# Present a view controller in the background

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am having a problem with presenting a view controller while another one is already presented.

In my app, I present a `UIImagePickerController`, which after selecting an image (either from the library or through the device's camera) should return to another view controller.

For example, let's say you clicked a camera button which launches the camera, and after you take a picture, the camera slides down, but the view you see is not the one with the camera button but a view which lets you edit the metadata of the image.

Does anyone know a way to accomplish this task?

Thanks ahead, iLyrical.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    NewViewController *viewController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.image = image;
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
}
```

And if you can use iOS 5.0 or newer:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(){
        NewViewController *viewController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
        viewController.image = image;
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Check Apple's doc on [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to initialize the final viewController before presenting UIImagePickerController, you can try:

1. Initialize final viewController
2. Set it hidden or its view's alpha=0 and push non-animated
3. Present imagePicker viewController
4. Set the final viewController non-hidden
5. Dismiss modal viewController